# Looking for a model on how to match a keyword / part(s) of word into a full name

Tags: python, nlp

Our data set is a lot of ship movements. A captain usually enters destination in form of a short code like: "*CHN*", "*Singapore*", "*XIAO HU*" etc.
These keywords are pretty short, can be somewhat misspelled and can be a code for a port, name of the city or just random gibberish depending on user's mood :)

We have a large dictionary of destination words and want to try and match the code into a real destination (Like Singapore Port X).

So, basically it's a word => words predictor, depending on earlier history (ie. same vessels usually goes on same route).

Is there a good NLP model to use to implement these kind of predictions? Right now we're using regular text/pattern matching and it WORKS, but thinking this could be solved better by ML.

Since we also have the actual trip data, we **do** know the actual destination afterwards, so it's possible to have a decent training data set. Unfortunately the captain might be different for same vessel on different trips, so the "style" of codes might not be consistent.